# Jekyll/Liquid, group by condition?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have my site posts:

```
{% assign a = site.posts | group_by:"title" | sort:"size" | reverse %}
```

I tried what I want with `where` and it's working

```
{% assign b = a| where_exp:"a", "a.name.size <= 5 " %}
{% for g in b -%}
  {{g.name}}({{g.size}})
{%- unless forloop.last%}、{% endunless %}
{%- endfor %}

{% assign b = a | where_exp:"a", "a.name.size > 5"%}
{% for g in b -%}
  {{g.name}}({{g.size}})
{%- unless forloop.last %}、{% endunless %}
{%- endfor %}
```

but can't get it work with `group by`:

```
{% assign a = a | group_by_exp:"a", "a.name.size > 5" %}
{% for b in a -%}
{% for g in b.items -%}
  {{g.name}}({{g.size}})
{% -unless forloop.last %}、{% endunless %}
{% -endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two examples filter the names shorter or equal than 5 and the names longer than 5.

In the other example you want to group by the names that are longer than 5, right?

I am not sure about your error message but your syntax looks almost correct:

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/:

**Where Expression**
*Select all the objects in an array where the expression is true.*

```
{{ site.members | where_exp:"item",
"item.graduation_year == 2014" }}`
```

**Group By Expression**
*Group an array's items using a Liquid expression.*

```
{{ site.members | group_by_exp: "item",
"item.graduation_year | truncate: 3, ''" }}

Result: [{"name"=>"201", "items"=>[...]},
        {"name"=>"200", "items"=>[...]}]
```

I assume you can group by the length of the names but not filter in the same step (>5). I think you first need to filter and return an array and then group it by name.

Example (untested):

```
{% assign a = site.posts | group_by:"title" | sort:"size" | reverse %}
{% assign b = a | where_exp:"a", "a.name.size > 5"%}
{% assign c = b | group_by_exp:"a", "a.name.size" %}
...
```

or maybe even in one step

```
{% assign a = site.posts | group_by:"title" | sort:"size" | reverse %}
{% assign b = a | where_exp:"a", "a.name.size > 5" | group_by_exp:"a", "a.name.size" %}
```